# How do i get a value in a dictionary of dictionarys when i dont care about the key of the outside value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file that contains 1440 lines just like this. I need a way to get the first 9 values of '4. close'

```
{
    '2020-10-30 20:00:00': {'1. open': '386.9900', '2. high': '387.0000', '3. low': '386.7100', '4. close': '387.0000', '5. volume': '3205'}, 
    '2020-10-30 19:59:00': {'1. open': '386.9800', '2. high': '387.0000', '3. low': '386.9000', '4. close': '387.0000', '5. volume': '4721'}, 
    '2020-10-30 19:58:00': {'1. open': '386.7000', '2. high': '386.9500', '3. low': '386.7000', '4. close': '386.9500', '5. volume': '1378'}, 
    '2020-10-30 19:57:00': {'1. open': '386.3500', '2. high': '386.6300', '3. low': '386.3500', '4. close': '386.6300', '5. volume': '1296'}, 
}
```

Comment: Also, this is the first question I have ever posted on StackOverflow, so i am not sure if i posed the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if d is your dictionary:

```
four_closes = [val['4. close'] for val in d.values()]
four_closes[:9]
```

Comment: @JustinMalone Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you. Also please avoid "thank you" comments as they are required to be deleted later.

Comment: Sorry, I had to look up how to accept an answer, the check-mark was not exactly intuitive.